# Duplicate a git repo locally

Tags: git

I've got an app in a git repo that I'd like to duplicate locally.  I don't have this project on GitHub, but I guess I could/maybe should.  I'm at a point where I want to make two versions of the same app on my local machine - I want to set one up to use an external database (Like AWS, but not sure as of writing this) and the other to just keep using the "internal" PostgreSQL database on Heroku.

Think of it as I'm at a point where I want to have a demo app that runs entirely on Heroku and a "production" app that uses AWS for storage.

How can I fork this local repo?

**Edit**

I've seen the instructions on [GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/), but not sure it will work for me since I haven't pushed to GitHub.

Comment: Why not use a branch?

Comment: Alright, think that might work - I kept searching for cloning, but see that branching may be a viable option as well.  Search terminology error on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any local directory can be used essentially just like a remote repo in any way. Handy sometimes if you want to push somewhere when you have no network.

Test it for yourself, create repo in dir 'a':

```
$ mkdir a
$ cd a
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/a/.git/
$ git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```

Create repo in dir 'b':

```
$ mkdir ../b
$ cd ../b
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/b/.git/
```

Add a commit to it:

```
$ echo foo > foo
$ git add foo
$ git commit foo -m 'commit 1'
[master (root-commit) b3c0319] commit 1
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 foo
```

Add the 'a' dir as a remote called 'local', and push to it:

```
$ git remote add local ../a
$ git push local master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 213 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
To ../a
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Now, to check it looks like any other remote, create repo in dir 'c':

```
$ mkdir ../c
$ cd ../c
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/c/.git/
```

Add the 'a' dir as a remote called 'local':

```
$ git remote add local ../a
```

Pull the commits (done in the 'b' repo):

```
$ git pull local master
From ../a
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 mjw mjw 4 Oct 31 23:41 foo
```

**Bare git repositories**

Note, if you make a git repo on your filesystem for your own use, you should create a "bare" repo (with `git init --bare`). This creates a git repo without the facility for working changes, which should not be allowed and is not useful in this context.

Comment: Thank you! Finally that what i've looked for my unreal project content folder which i want to track is too big for GitHub. Now i can push changes in it to another hard drive, without fear of ssd death someday.

Comment: @RyanKane It didn't really occur to me anyone would do that, it's fine of course, but you should use a "bare" repo to push to, I updated the answer to append a comment about this.

Answer (score 2):

You can just:

```
git clone myrepo myrepocopy
```

It doesn't have to be on a remote server. Or you could create a branch which it sounds like you probably want to do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Git allows cloning from the filesystem in the same syntax as from http(s):

```
git clone file:///home/mamba/programming/so/git/repo.git repo2
```